# Create JsonObject that has JsonArray from list of objects using Java ee

Tags: java, json

I want to create a JSONARRAY from a List of objects and add it inside JsonObject and vice versa.
I am using javax.json-api-1.0 lib.
here is what I have tried but it's not working. the result i got is {"type":"friends_list","array":[]}

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<UserModel> users = new ArrayList<>();
        UserModel user1 = new UserModel(0, "name1", "name1@gmail", "online");
        UserModel user2 = new UserModel(1, "name2", "name2@gmail", "offline");
        users.add(user1);
        users.add(user2);

        JsonObject jo = fromListOfUsers(users);
        System.out.println(jo.toString());
    }
public static JsonObject fromListOfUsers(List<UserModel> users) {
        JsonArrayBuilder jsonArray = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        for (UserModel user : users) {
            jsonArray.add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("id", user.getId())
                    .add("name", user.getName())
                    .add("email", user.getEmail())
                    .add("online_status", user.getOnline_status()).build());
        }
        jsonArray.build();

         JsonObject obj = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                 .add("type","friends_list")
                .add("array", jsonArray)
                .build();
        return obj;        
    }
```

Comment: What result did you get?

Comment: edited. check again

Comment: When creating a JsonObject in loop you forgot to do build()

Comment: worked for me thank you